# Why does my site display differently on a mobile device when scrollbars are not present

Tags: css

When viewing my website from an iPhone or iPad my site displays just fine when scrollbars on present. However, when you access a page when scroll bars are not needed the display gets messed up. I have no idea how to resolve this issue. Any ideas?

For an example my website is [www.surfboardswap.com](http://www.surfboardswap.com). The homepage appears fine on a mobile device. But if you access [www.surfboardswap.com/alerts](http://www.surfboardswap.com/alerts) the display does not fit on the page since scroll bars are not needed.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I dont see any problems, everything just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like both those links you provided render with scroll bars depending on the width of my browser screen. I think you're ultimate issue here is responsive design.

You have a width set on your .container css selector. This is breaking the responsiveness of you're site, because it's being forced to that width even on smaller screens. Try removing that!

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking a look. I just gave your suggestion a shot but no luck. Seemed to cause various other display issues.

Comment: @hanesjw try setting that parameter to width: 100% . Having it set the way you currently do is taking away from all the bootstrap magic that will make your site render well on mobile devices.

Comment: I think you might be on to something. It definitely made the page fit inside the bounds of the screen, however it caused a few other display issues to appear. Maybe I can tweak it to fix the newly created issues now and go from there. Thanks for taking a look!